# IndProp: ev_plus_plus

Tags: coq, logical-foundations

```
(** **** Exercise: 3 stars, standard, optional (ev_plus_plus)

    This exercise just requires applying existing lemmas.  No
    induction or even case analysis is needed, though some of the
    rewriting may be tedious. *)

Theorem ev_plus_plus : forall n m p,
  even (n+m) -> even (n+p) -> even (m+p).
Proof.
  intros n m p H1 H2.
```

Here is what I got:

```
1 subgoal (ID 89)

n, m, p : nat
H1 : even (n + m)
H2 : even (n + p)
============================
even (m + p)
```

I have proven the previous theorem:

```
Theorem ev_ev__ev : forall n m,
  even (n+m) -> even n -> even m.
```

And wanted to apply it to H1, but

```
apply ev_ev__ev in H1.
```

gives an error:

```
Error: Unable to find an instance for the variable m.
```

Why can't it find "m" in the expression `even (n + m)`? How to fix?

**Update**

```
apply ev_ev__ev with (m:=m) in H1.
```

gives a very strange result:

```
2 subgoals (ID 90)

n, m, p : nat
H1 : even m
H2 : even (n + p)
============================
even (m + p)

subgoal 2 (ID 92) is:
 even (n + m + m)
```

I thought that it will transform H1 to 2 hypothesis:

```
H11 : even n
H12 : even m
```

But instead it gave 2 subgoals, the second that we need to prove is more complicated than the initial one:

```
even (n + m + m)
```

What's happening here?

Comment: No, you will not get `H11` and `H12` by applying `ev_ev__ev`.  You can only get the hypothesis `even n -> even m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement `forall n m,  even (n+m) -> even n -> even m.` does not mean "if we have that (n + m) is even then we have both that n is even and that m is even" (this is false, consider n = m = 1).  Instead it means "if we have that (n+m) is even, and we have that n is even, then we have that m is even".

There is no way to get `H11 : even n` and `H12 : even m` just from `H1 : even (n + m)` without assuming a contradiction.  I would suggest figuring out how to prove your theorem with pen and paper before trying to prove it in Coq.

Answer (score 1):

Because Coq can't figure out what value it should give for m. You can apply the tactic  `eapply ev_ev__ev in H1.` and see the goals

```
  n, m, p : nat
  H2 : even (n + p)
  H1 : even ?m
  ============================
  even (m + p)

subgoal 2 (ID 17) is:
 even (n + m + ?m)
```

Coq has instantiated the m with a meta variable ?m, and you need to give a witness for this meta variable in the end to finish the proof.

Second approach is just apply the tactic with instantiating the value of m `apply ev_ev__ev with (m := m) in H1.`

You can see more on apply with tactics in software-foundations https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/Tactics.html

Comment: @user4035 Sorry, I did not check it for couple of days. I did not pay attention to proof details, but I was more focused on making sure that apply tactic succeed.

Answer (score 1):

The thing that is happening is that Coq unifies `H1` with the `even n` argument of `ev_ev__ev` instead of the `even (n+m)`.

You can tell Coq exactly where you want `H1` to go, and use `_` wildcards for the places where you let Coq work out the details.

You probably wanted this the term `ev_ev__ev n m H1` with type `even n -> even m` but your `apply` produced the term `ev_ev__ev (n+m) m _ H1`  which also left you with some more stuff to prove.  To take a look at the proof context, do

```
Check ev_ev__ev (n+m) m _ H1.
```